# How to send notification from a worker in Android 13? (MAUI Android)

Tags: c#, android, maui

I would like to use a worker to do some periodic task.

For notifications, I am using Plugin.LocalNotifications.

When I try to send a notification, it is not sent.

This is the code of the DoWork of the worker:

```
public override Result DoWork()
    {
        NotificationRequest miRequest = new NotificationRequest
        {
            NotificationId = 1000,
            Title = "Título de notificación",
            BadgeNumber = 42,
            Schedule = new NotificationRequestSchedule
            {
                NotifyTime = DateTime.Now,
            },
        };

        LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(miRequest);


        return Result.InvokeSuccess();
    }
```

I don't know if it is because the worker works in background or perhaps I need some kind of permissions in Android. But in the manifest I have this permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

How could I sent some notifications in my worker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the android 13, you also need to [request the `android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS` at run time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java). So you can use the following code to request the notification permission in the MainActivity's `OnCreate` or `OnStart` method:

```
const int requestNotification = 0;
string[] notiPermission =
  {
      Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
  };

if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;
if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
   {
      this.RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestNotification);
   }
```

**Note: If your project's target framework is .net6.0, you need to update it to .net7.0. Because the `Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications` can only used in the .net7.0 and higher.**

Comment: Another options would be not ask, and configure in settings, in notifications, to allow the application publish notifications, but it is more easy for the user to be asked the first time the application is used.

Comment: This is the update in the Android 13.0. The app must be granted the notification permission by the user and then it can send notification. @ÁlvaroGarcía

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT How can I request PostNotification permission in xamarin forms app for Android 13 version?  I asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692494/foreground-service-dont-push-notification

Comment: I can request PostNotification permission in xamarin forms app with the Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.9.0 Preview 2.0. You can update the visual studio or update the android sdk to do that. @MertAltiparmak

Comment: I update android target version 12 to 13, then my problem solved. @LiyunZhang-MSFT thank you for fast answer.