# Foreground service don't push notification

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, service

I created foreground service, it needs to send a notification but it doesn't send.

It looks fine, service starting and I can see from console but it doesn't push any notification ? I can't find where I'm doing wrong or missing. My expectation from this service "not restart app when user want to resume from background". My main problem is my app restart when resume from background.
If I success about sending notification from service my app does restart again when user resume from background ?

Update : I could push notification at android 12 but I can't in android 13 with this code.

```
 public void StartForegroundService()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ForegroundService));

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartService(intent);
        }
        else if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.R)
        {
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
        }
       

    }
```

Update 2 :

[image]

Interface :

```
public interface IForegroundService
{
    void StartForegroundService();
    void StopForegroundService();

    bool IsForegroundServiceRunning();
}
```

Android Manifest :

I add those to my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Service :

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(ForegroundService))]
namespace İdaServis.Droid.Services
{
[Service]
public class ForegroundService : Service, IForegroundService
{
    public static bool IsForegroundServiceRunning;
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while(true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Foreground Service Running.");
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
            }

        });

        string channelID = "ForegroundServiceChannel";

        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, channelID, NotificationImportance.Default);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        var not = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
            .SetContentTitle("İda Servis App Çalışıyor")
            .SetContentText("Servis Çalışıyor")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
            .SetPriority(1)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetChannelId(channelID)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .Build();

        StartForeground(1001,not);
        return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();    
        IsForegroundServiceRunning = true;
    }
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        IsForegroundServiceRunning = false;
    }
    public void StartForegroundService()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ForegroundService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
    }

    public void StopForegroundService()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ForegroundService));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StopService(intent);
    }

    bool IForegroundService.IsForegroundServiceRunning()
    {
        return IsForegroundServiceRunning;
    }
}
```

}

Broadcast Receiver :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] {Intent.ActionBootCompleted})]
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
        {
            var foregroundServiceIntent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ForegroundService));
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
            context.StartForegroundService(foregroundServiceIntent);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the Android version of the device you are testing and the target SDK version? Did you add and ask the notification permission? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

Comment: My emulator android 13 and android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="33"

Comment: If you do not ask the notification permission, you will see notices related to foreground services in the Task Manager but don't see them in the notification drawer.
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services

Comment: You can try adding and requesting permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`

Comment: I could push notification at Android 12 but I can't at Android 13. Where I miss things for android 13 ? I update question now.

Comment: Does this answer of Liyun: [How to send notification from a worker in Android 13? (MAUI Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76258994/19902734) solve?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I'm going to try Liyun's solution but I can't find how to request this permission in xamarin forms.

Comment: ？Just put the code into OnCreate(), then it will prompt you to add `using Android;` .

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT There is no PostNotification request for me.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I add a picture to my question.

Comment: You mean you don't have `Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications` ?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Yes. Liyun says in note, Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications can only used in the .net7.0 and higher. My project net standart 2.0. Should I upgrade my project ? I'm still learner and I'm stuck here.

Comment: What's your version of [Xamarin.Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCX91.png) and [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2MvB.png) ?

Comment: Xamarin forms  version : 5.0.0.2612 Android Target Framework 12 @JianweiSun-MSFT

Comment: Change Android Target Framework 12 to 13 and save it.

Comment: I lost connection with emulator, I think android 13 sdk's doesn't installed. I'm downloading and  will try my app.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT Thank you a lot! Really! I can see notification now. But It works when I reopen app. Is that normal ?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I opened another topic a few days ago. My main problem is that when user want to back to my app from background app start from beginning. Do you know anything about this issue ?

Comment: *But It works when I reopen app. Is that normal ?* Try to release the app.

Comment: Okey I'll it but Its not a fatal error for me. The other issue is main problem. I'm reading topics about that but noone share any solution.

Comment: *I opened another topic a few days ago. My main problem is that when user want to back to my app from background app start from beginning. Do you know anything about this issue ?* Have a look at this case: [How to create a never ending background service in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107522/how-to-create-a-never-ending-background-service-in-xamarin-forms), wish it can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as an answer, use the following code by [Liyun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76258994/19902734):

```cs
const int requestNotification = 0;
string[] notiPermission =
  {
      Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
  };

if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;
if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
   {
      this.RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestNotification);
   }
```

For xamarin forms, be sure that Android Target Framework is 13 or 13 later version.